# I bought seeds for Calendula Officinalis Sunset Buff.

Tags: identification

The plant of this calendula is now 6 feet tall and is showing long spikes of flowers which, at this time, are still dawdling to come out. I would love to know what this plant is as it is driving me nuts. I am a keen gardener but this plant has me humbugged.
Thank you for your kind help.[image]

Comment: Did you buy this from a seed catalogue?  If so, the chances are they sell the seeds to this plant in their catalogue.  Also, is there a smell to the leaves?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Are the leaves fragrant (such as when you rub a leaf and smell your fingers)?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be ragweed. At this time of year in northern latitudes they are everywhere, they self-seed prolifically. In fact this ragweed plant is already in full flower, it's just that the flowers are tiny and quite hard to see. It could either be a volunteer from a seed of a previous year, or mixed in with your seed packet if from an unreliable source.

Take care if you attempt to pull it up for the compost - likely it has a good root system at that height and yanking on the roots might disturb other more important neighbours. An alternative is to cut it right at soil level and watch for side shoots.

Edit: height is not unusual for *Ambrosia artemisiifolia* - see for example "Newcomb's Guide to Wildflowers", Lawrence Newcomb, Little Brown & Company 1977, on page 438 "1-6' high".

Comment: Definitely NOT ragweed. Giant Ragweed is the correct height but the leaves are three-lobed, and Common Ragweed has similar leaves (but cut more like an Artemisa) but is no more than 2-3 feet high.

Comment: EDIT of the above... I suppose it could be some of the lesser-known species, but those are mostly west of the Rockies and south of the US. Where do you live? I've done some research and found a few that resemble your photo, but the height of those is in the 12-18" range, not 6 feet. A close-up of the buds would be helpful as well.